# I am trying to break an JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I coded a little script to make a little animation, but when I move the cursor 10 times very fast over the div, the div moves 10 times. I make a global var and a if query, but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
var working = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#div1").attr("style", "position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;");
    $("#div2").attr("style", "position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;");
    $("#div3").attr("style", "position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;");
    $("#div4").attr("style", "position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:0px;");
});

function animon(id) {
    if (working == true) return false;
    var working = true;
    if (id == "1") $("#div1").animate({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '0px',
        left: '60px'
    }, "slow");
    if (id == "2") $("#div2").animate({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '0px',
        right: '60px'
    }, "slow");
    if (id == "3") $("#div3").animate({
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: '0px',
        left: '60px'
    }, "slow");
    if (id == "4") $("#div4").animate({
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: '0px',
        right: '60px'
    }, "slow");
}

function animoff(id) {
    if (id == "1") $("#div1").animate({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '0px',
        left: '0px'
    }, "slow");
    if (id == "2") $("#div2").animate({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '0px',
        right: '0px'
    }, "slow");
    if (id == "3") $("#div3").animate({
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: '0px',
        left: '0px'
    }, "slow");
    if (id == "4") $("#div4").animate({
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: '0px',
        right: '0px'
    }, "slow");
    var working = false;
}
```

The animon() function ist bounded at the onmouseover event and the animoff() function to the onmouseout event. The working boolean does check if an div container is moved.

Comment: you should use the .stop() function to stop the previous animations.

Comment: Scope confusion at line 11: `var working=true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div1").attr("style", "position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;");
    $("#div2").attr("style", "position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;");
    $("#div3").attr("style", "position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;");
    $("#div4").attr("style", "position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:0px;");
});
function animon(id){
    if(id=="1")
        $("#div1").stop(true).animate({position:'absolute',top:'0px',left:'60px'},"slow");
    if(id=="2")
        $("#div2").stop(true).animate({position:'absolute',top:'0px',right:'60px'},"slow");
    if(id=="3")
        $("#div3").stop(true).animate({position:'absolute',bottom:'0px',left:'60px'},"slow");
    if(id=="4")
        $("#div4").stop(true).animate({position:'absolute',bottom:'0px',right:'60px'},"slow");
}
function animoff(id){
    if(id=="1")
        $("#div1").stop(true).animate({position:'absolute',top:'0px',left:'0px'},"slow");
    if(id=="2")
        $("#div2").stop(true).animate({position:'absolute',top:'0px',right:'0px'},"slow");
    if(id=="3")
        $("#div3").stop(true).animate({position:'absolute',bottom:'0px',left:'0px'},"slow");
    if(id=="4")
        $("#div4").stop(true).animate({position:'absolute',bottom:'0px',right:'0px'},"slow");
}
```